# SonarQube Analysis Parameters: setting per project parameters

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 5.6.1 and I have a few interdependent projects. I have them building and analyzing separately and cleanly, so that's not an issue.

I've got a global SonarQube.Analysis.xml with the sonar.host.url, sonar.user, and sonar.password (since they don't change).

I'd like to set the ProjectName, ProjectKey, and ProjectVersion on a by project basis but I can't figure out how. I've tried a second SonarQube.Analysis.xml but that just replaces the global one. I've tried to set them in the csproj but I can't get those recognized.

Ultimately, I'd like to have the ProductVersion set as the AssemblyVersion and the others set on a per project basis.

Answer (score 1):

From comments at the top of the SonarQube.Analysis.xml file:

> Note that the following properties cannot be set through an MSBuild project file or an SonarQube.Analysis.xml file:
>
> sonar.projectName, sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectVersion
>
> The following flags need to be used to set their value:
>
> /n:[SonarQube Project Name] /k:[SonarQube Project Key] /v:[SonarQube Project Version]

So it looks like this is futile. I'm just gonna have to add them to each bat file.